# How can I append to an empty two dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, windows

Here I am reading data from a text file where rows are delimited by string `OUT_` and columns are delimited by `\n`

I am filtering data and throwing out any arrays `<9` in col length and not having `%` at col 6

Then I want to sort alphabetically by col `0`, and group all arrays with the same name in col `0`

Returning a triple array

```
        async function fetchText() {
            let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080//data.txt');

            let dataOut = await response.text();
            var n = dataOut.split("OUT_");
            var lastTester = "";
            var new_array = [[[]]];
            for (var x in n) {
                var m = n[x].split("\n");
                var temp_array = [[]];
                if (m.length > 9)
                    if (m[6].indexOf('%') > -1) {

                        temp_array.push(m);
                        
                        if (lastTester !== m[0]) {
                            new_array.push(temp_array);
                            temp_array = [[]];
                            document.write("Appended ");
                        }
                        lastTester = m[0];
                    }
            }
            return new_array;
        }
        tester_array = fetchText();
        document.write(tester_array[1][1][0]);
        document.write(tester_array.length());
```

However, I am not getting any output on either of, it seems `tester_array` is empty

```
    document.write(tester_array[1][1][0]);
    document.write(tester_array.length());
```

It writes `Appended`  to the web page, so it's not a data input or text file problem,

What am I doing wrong with the array creation and appending?
What needs to be changed in the code?

The `data.txt` file looks like this (edited to remove confidential information):

```
OUT_FusingPower BI
Manufacturing Central
|
Pages
MFG Yield Summary
%100
%100
%100
MFG Yield Trend
MFG Error Details
Yield by Line/Tester
EC FR by Line/Tester
OLR Report
Tester Comparision
Yield by Part Number
Test Time
OUT_Tester by Station
Error Code Details
Yield by Site
About
File
%100
%100
%100
%100
OUT_Analytics - Errorcode Failure Rate by Line/Tester
Site
All
Project
Rumba  
%100
%100
%100
All
Station
All
Current Week?
Multiple selections
Shift
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function is async, and you are not waiting for resolving the promise. Therefore, upon accessing tester_array, the promise is not yet fullfiled.

```
fetchText().then(result => {
  console.log(result[1][1][0])
  console.log(result.length)
})
```

You can use **.then**, or you would need to use async/await approach.

```js
async function fetchText() {
    let dataOut = 
        `OUT_FusingPower BI
        Manufacturing Central
        |
        Pages
        MFG Yield Summary
        %100
        %100
        %100
        MFG Yield Trend
        MFG Error Details
        Yield by Line/Tester
        EC FR by Line/Tester
        OLR Report
        Tester Comparision
        Yield by Part Number
        Test Time
        OUT_Tester by Station
        Error Code Details
        Yield by Site
        About
        File
        %100
        %100
        %100
        %100
        OUT_Analytics - Errorcode Failure Rate by Line/Tester
        Site
        All
        Project
        Rumba  
        %100
        %100
        %100
        All
        Station
        All
        Current Week?
        Multiple selections
        Shift`;
    var n = dataOut.split("OUT_");
    var lastTester = "";
    var new_array = [[[]]];
    for (var x in n) {
        var m = n[x].split("\n");
        var temp_array = [[]];
        if (m.length > 9)
            if (m[6].indexOf('%') > -1) {

                temp_array.push(m);

                if (lastTester !== m[0]) {
                    new_array.push(temp_array);
                    temp_array = [[]];
                    console.log("Appended");
                }
                lastTester = m[0];
            }
    }
    return new_array;
}

fetchText().then(result => {
    console.log(result[1][1][0]);
    console.log(result.length);
})
```

Comment: Or could I just add an await keyword? 
            `tester_array = await fetchText();`

Comment: await can be only used inside async function scope. Your variable tester_array is being called in global scope. As you can see inside your async function you are already awaiting the fetch to happen, so that you can use it inside it later on, when the data is received. But all of that happens inside that async function scope, meaning to use it outside it as you call your fetchText() async function so that you can use the return value from it, you need to wait for that to happen. Which can be obtained by using .then(), or you could wrap it in another async function that would be awaiting for it